# What does the parameter `-e` in `sed` commands do?

Tags: command-line, sed

man sed says:

```
-e script, --expression=script
          add the script to the commands to be executed
```

[The description on gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) says:

```
`-e SCRIPT'
`--expression=SCRIPT'
 Add the commands in SCRIPT to the set of commands to be run while
 processing the input.
```

What does that mean? What would be the difference between a sed command with and without `-e`?

*I'm trying to learn about sed*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-e` you can run multiple `sed` scripts with one command, like

```
sed -e /23/d -e s/foo/bar/
```

(delete any line containing `23` and replace `foo` with `bar`)